# Sort Dict by Values in Python 3.6+

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, sorting, dictionary

I was looking for a method to sort a dictionary in Python with its values, after a few attempts, is what it comes:

```
a = {<populated dict...>}
a = {v: k for k, v in a.items()}
a = {v: k for k, v in sorted(a.items())}
```

This code seems to work, but I think it's poor for performance, is there a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Comment: @newbie, not sure how a question that sorts by key is a dupe for one asking for sort by value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the dictionary is sorted based on keys, but the sorted function takes  a function as a parameter using which you can alter the behaviour for
program.

```
d={'a':6,'b':4,'k':3}
print(sorted(d)) 

sorted_by_values= sorted(d,key=lambda x:d[x])
print(sorted_by_values)
```

Answer (score 19):

You do not need to do the double key/value swap, you can do this:

```
a = {k: v for k, v in sorted(a.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])}
```

([sorted DOCS](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted))

#### Test Code:

```
data = dict(a=1, b=3, c=2)
print(data)
data_sorted = {k: v for k, v in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])}
print(data_sorted)
```

#### Results:

From CPython 3.6, and guaranteed in all python implementations 3.7+:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 2}
{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 3}
```

Comment: In what way will this sort the dictionary?

Comment: @PeterWood, In CPython 3.6 and Python 3.7+ Dicts are ordered.

Comment: I don't like it as an approach. Insertion sort is a feature since 3.6 but `The order-preserving aspect of this new implementation is considered an implementation detail and should not be relied upon` from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html)

Comment: @newbie, your are technically correct.  However, for 99% of the world, CPython is Python.  And for this feature at least, in 3.7 it is no longer an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me. Not sure how efficient is this.

```
sorted_list_by_value=sorted(data_dict, key=data_dict.__getitem__)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the top answer but without the dict comprehension, resulting in marginally faster and shorter code:

**Code:**

```
dict(sorted(a.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

`sorted` returns a list of tuples, which `dict()` then uses as its key/value pairs.

**Example:**

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 2}
a = dict(sorted(a.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
print(a)
```

Results:

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 3}
```

Works in CPython 3.6+ and all Pythons 3.7+.

Answer (score -1):

otherwise create a list of keys in the order you want.

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
d = {1: 1, 2:4, 5:2, 9:3}
sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

Edited to include sort into sorted dict

Comment: OrderedDict preserves the order in which the keys are inserted and does not store them in increasing or decreasing order by value.

Comment: In old version of python dicts were explicitly unordered so if you wanted to sort a dict you'd need to do something like `OrderedDict(sorted(d,key=lambda x:d[x]))` the accepted answer isn't a "sorted dict" it's a sorted iterable of tuples